# Documentation of loop over item

Tags: loops, sourcecode, resources

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356318/4011) answer there is a loop construct used called `loop over item`. I am looking for a documentation of this and for a reference in which file it is defined.

```
 \ifdate{workday} {
  \tikzset{every workday/.try, vacation name=,
    loop over item/.code args={##1/##2/##3}{%
      \ifdate{between=##1 and ##2}{%
        \tikzset{every vacation/.try, vacation name/.expanded=##3}%
      }{}},
    loop over item/.list/.expanded=\vacations}%
  }{}
```

I already searched the tikz documentation for it and grepped my texlive directory but didn't find it.

Comment: The `.list` thingy is explained on page 890 of the pgfmanual. The whole section 82 is a great reference for the pgfkeys, which are at work here. As far as I understand things, the `.list` key makes the key before loop over whatever is after the `=` sign (`\avations` in this case, which also gets expanded because of the `.expanded` key). BTW, as far as I understand things, this `loop over item` by itself is, despite what its name suggests, not a loop, but "just" a code. However, due to the `.list` key, it becomes a loop

Comment: `loop over item/.code=blah` suggests that it is a user-defined macro. There should not be documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything I am going to say here is much better explained in section 82 of the pgfmanual. `loop over item` by itself is, despite what its name suggests, not a loop, but "just" a code. However, due to the `.list` key, it becomes a loop. To see that more clearly, consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor} % .list requires pgffor
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/student/.cd, % switch to student
hello/.code={hello #1!}}
\pgfkeys{/student/hello=world}

\pgfkeys{/student/hello/.list={world,duck,koala,marmot}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `hello` is just a simple code that prints `hello <arg>!`, where `arg` is the argument. (If you have a definition inside a definition, you need to increase the number of `#`, as explained e.g [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42464/121799). This is the reason why there are two `#` in the definition of `\ifdate`.)

What is important now is that the `.list` key makes the code loop over the argument, as can be seen in (the admittedly stupid example) `\pgfkeys{/student/hello/.list={world,duck,koala,marmot}}`. Note also that `.list` requires the `pgffor` library (on top of `pgfkeys`, which would be sufficient to make the first part of the MWE work).