# Tikz: How to append style to avoid styles spilling across nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

My MWE is based on the excellent [template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356224/tikz-calendar-loop-through-array-of-dates-to-mark-vacations). The original template defines a `\vacations` command to store the dates of the vacation and the text to be printed; it defines some styles for each of these; and then loops over the calendar dates to apply these styles and print the text. I have tried to adapt the template, but the styles leak across nodes.

**Maybe something wrong with my use of `.append style`?**

MWE Expected output: Holidays have gray background and orange text color, other days have white background and black text color.

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}

% set current year
\def\currentyear{\the\year}

% set vacation dates
\newcommand*\vacationdata{%
  \currentyear-09-02/\currentyear-09-02/Holiday%
}

% set all styles
\tikzset{%
  every day/.style={
     minimum height=0.8cm, 
     text width=5cm, 
     draw=gray
  },
  every day name/.style={
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  every vacation/.style={
    every day/.append style={
      fill=gray!30,
      text=orange,
    }
  },
  vacation name/.initial=,
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar[
  dates=\currentyear-09-01 to \currentyear-09-03,
  name=cal,
  day code={%
    % print the calendar day number
    \node [name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname, every day/.try] {\tikzdaytext};
    % print the calendar day name
    \node [anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=0.5cm]\pgfcalendarsuggestedname.west)
        {\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};
    % print the vacation name
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/vacation name}{%
      \node [every vacation/.try,text width=3cm,xshift=1cm] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vacation name}};
    }{}%
  },
  execute before day scope={
    % set vacation name
    \tikzset{every vacation/.try, vacation name=,
      loop over item/.code args={##1/##2/##3}{%
        \ifdate{between=##1 and ##2}{%
          \tikzset{every vacation/.try, vacation name/.expanded=##3}%
        }{}},
      loop over item/.list/.expanded=\vacationdata}%
   },
   execute at begin day scope={%
     \pgftransformyshift{-1*\pgfcalendarcurrentday cm}
   }
];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main change is to test whether key `/tikz/vacation name` has an empty value, since it is always defined.

Not sure if the area having background color is the desired.

```tex
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,calendar}

% set current year
\def\currentyear{\the\year}

% set vacation dates
\newcommand*\vacationdata{%
  \currentyear-09-02/\currentyear-09-02/Holiday%
}

% set all styles
\tikzset{%
  every day/.style={
     minimum height=0.8cm, 
     text width=5cm, 
     draw=gray
  },
  every day name/.style={
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  every vacation/.style={
    every day/.append style={
      fill=gray!30,
      text=orange,
    }
  },
  vacation name/.initial=,
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar[
  dates=\currentyear-09-01 to \currentyear-09-03,
  name=cal,
  day code={%
    % print the calendar day number
    \node [name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname, every day/.try] {\tikzdaytext};
    % print the calendar day name
    \node [anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=0.5cm]\pgfcalendarsuggestedname.west)
        {\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};
    % print the vacation name
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/vacation name}{\mytemp}%
    \ifx\mytemp\empty
    \else
      \node [every vacation/.try, every day/.try, text width=3cm,xshift=1cm] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/vacation name}};
    \fi
  },
  execute before day scope={
    % set vacation name
    \tikzset{vacation name=,
      loop over item/.code args={##1/##2/##3}{%
        \ifdate{between=##1 and ##2}{%
          \tikzset{vacation name/.expanded=##3}%
        }{}},
      loop over item/.list/.expanded=\vacationdata}%
   },
   execute at begin day scope={%
     \pgftransformyshift{-1*\pgfcalendarcurrentday cm}%
   }
];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, very clever, I would never have found this one! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, noted the baselines of "Thu" and "Holiday" are slightly mis-aligned because only `y` in `Holiday` has a descender. You can play with tikz options `text height` and `text depth`, see pgfmanual sec. 5.1 "Styling the Nodes".

Comment: +1: Comment on the last comment: Maybe \strut would help

Comment: I've been able to adapt the code to a bigger project! With 6 months on a single page, the misalignment you noted is not perceptible. Here is the full code I'm using for reference (don't hesitate to comment further). Thanks again!! https://pastebin.com/wBDcnzZ8

Comment: For better text alignment, try the `mid` anchors (eg `mid west`)